# azure cli failover groups

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am looking at creating a sql server failover group using the azure cli. The following command is being used :

```
az sql failover-group create --name sql1-fg --resource-group sql1 --server sql1 --partner-server sq1l-dr --partner-resource-group sql1-dr --failover-policy Manual
```

However I get the following error :

> Grace period value should not be provided when failover policy Manual
>   is selected for the read-write endpoint

I have not passed in this parameter but with grace-period being a default parameter with a value of 1, my query is how do I exclude this from the command line. I have tried setting to 0, -1, $false, $null, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on my side, I think it may be a bug of Azure CLI, because it is unreasonable.

Even if I create the failover group with `Automatic` first, then use the [`az sql failover-group update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/failover-group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-failover-group-update) to set the `--failover-policy` to `Manual`, it always gives the same error message.

[image]

I have opened a new issue in the [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7215), you could check it. Or you could create the `Automatic` group first, and set it to `Manual` in the portal.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did think it was a bug myself but thought I would check first in case there was a way in the cli to override default parameters. I will keep an eye on the issue within github. As you suggested I had already just created it as Automatic and updated it in the portal.